# Can anyone explain me this --kill-at linker option?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am java programmer and working on JNI. To generate valid DLL file i need to add -Wl,--kill-at  linker option in my Eclipse CDT. But I don't know why we require --kill-at and What is it.

After searching on net I got below details from [this link.](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/Options.html)

But I don't understand it properly. Can any one explain me this in details ?

```
--kill-at
If given, the stdcall suffixes (@nn) will be stripped from symbols before they are    exported.
[This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a `__stdcall` function will have a suffix consisting of an `@` followed by the number of bytes of parameters that function expects, so (for example) a function `F` that takes 3 parameters of 4 bytes apiece would get a name (in the object file) of `F@12`.

This flag tells the linker that when it creates a DLL, it should *not* include those suffixes on function names -- if you've given a function the name `F`, the exported name should just be `F`.

Answer (score 1):

On Microsoft systems (PE executable/DLL format), the calling convention `stdcall` generates mangled symbols of the form `symbolname@number`. From the description, `--kill-at` causes the names exported from DLLs to just be `symbolname` even if they use the `stdcall` calling convention.